# Dockerコンテナの立ち上げ、ブラウザでの表示

Tags: docker

#### 現状

以下YouTube動画を見ながら、dockerを活用したrailsの環境構築を行なっています。しかし、コンテナが立ち上がったと表示されない。
`docker container run -p 8000:8000 --name webrick sample/webrick:latest` が開けない）
※しかし、`docker ps -a` で見る限りは立ち上がっているようです。

01:07:00付近 アプリを作成実行しよう

[Docker超入門講座 合併版 | ゼロから実践する4時間のフルコース (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZD1MIHwMBY&list=RDCMUC452hry4DI_pDn_CVT9ZKhQ&start_radio=1&rv=lZD1MIHwMBY&t=2939)

**実行環境:**
M1 Mac
Iterms
homebrew
docker
git
VScode　　　　　　各インストール済
dockerhub login済み

#### やりたいこと

ブラウザで `http://localhost:8000` を表示させて、YouTubeの教材と同じように進みたい。

#### 実際に出てるエラーメッセージ

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: ".": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

参考画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 既に試したこと

エラーメッセージで検索したところ、複数の解決方法があるようですが、それぞれ違うアプローチ方法なので変にいじるとまずいと判断し、お伺いしている次第です。

Comment: 文字で表示される情報は、画面キャプチャではなく「文字のまま」質問に貼り付けてください。

Answer (score 1):

コマンドが間違っています。末尾に余計な `.` が付いています。

実行したいのは

```sh
docker container run -p 8000:8000 --name webrick sample/webrick:latest
```

ですが、実際に実行されているのは

```sh
docker container run -p 8000:8000 --name webrick sample/webrick:latest .
```

です。

したがって `.` が exec されようとして `unable to start container process: exec: ".": executable file not found in $PATH` というエラーメッセージにつながっています。

Comment: nekketsuuu様 ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り修正しました。 が、別のエラーが出、構文エラーのようで確認しましたが、main.rbには問題がないように思えます。（参考画像追加文をご確認頂ければと思います）

Comment: お手数おかけしますが、ご回答いただけますと幸いです

Comment: @NagaiHiroki 新しく出てきたエラーは別の問題になってしまうので、別途新しい質問を作るようにしてみてください。追記された部分は一旦ロールバックしておきました。過去の内容は編集履歴から辿れます。